# how to cast response object to an object

Tags: objective-c

```
[manager POST:urlString parameters:[self jsonDict] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

        NSLog(@"response data: %@", responseObject);


        NSArray *postFromResponse = [ responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"credentials"];
    NSLog(@"credentials:%@", postFromResponse);

        for(NSDictionary *object in postFromResponse)
        {
            NSString *AccessKeyId = [object valueForKeyPath:@"AccessKeyId"];
            NSLog(@"%@", AccessKeyId);
        }



}
```

It gives me error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x79ea4430> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key AccessKeyId'

Comment: `for(NSDictionary *object in postFromResponse)`: `postFromResponse` seems to have some `NSString` and not only `NSDictionary` objects (if not all `NSString`). That's why, in the case of `object` being a `NSString`, you can't call `valueForKeyPath` on it. Or is it because `responseObject` is a `NSString` and not a `NSDictionary`?. It's not clear which line is causing the issue, and showing us the JSON could help.

Comment: my response is: credentials = { AccessKeyId = abac; SecretAccessKey = "99"; SessionToken = "rt"; };

Comment: Please update (edit it) your question with that, and specify if it's the value of  `postFromResponse` or `responseObject`.

Comment: Its from postFromResponse value. its inside dictionary value such as AccessKeyId, SessionId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSArray *postFromResponse = [responseDict valueforkey:@"credentials"];
for(NSDictionary *object in postFromResponse) {
  NSString *AccessKeyId = [object valueforkey:@"AccessKeyId"];
  NSLog(@"%@", AccessKeyId);
}
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a0abc50' ..sorry It gives me an error:

Comment: my response is: credentials =     {
        AccessKeyId = abac;
       
        SecretAccessKey = "99";
        SessionToken = "rt";
    };

Comment: try nsstring *a= [[responseDict valueforkey:@"credentials"]valueforkey:@"AccessKeyId"];

Comment: sorry it gives me Null value

Comment: How to you cast this value to nssobject attributes example : object.accessId I get null when casting this value to new object attribute

Comment: Nd object *obj=[NSOBJECT ALLOC] INIT;  obj. Accessid=[response valueforkey@""];

Comment: Thanks , but I want to access from anywhere. I can do within response class but If I go outside response class, then I get Null value. Any suggessted answers?

Comment: if you access anywhere   Nd object *obj=[NSOBJECT ALLOC] INIT; obj. Accessid=[response valueforkey@""]; [array addobject:obj];         for(nsobject *obj in array){}